# Can not find the error PHP MYSQL JSON ANDROID

Tags: android, mysql, json, logcat

Can anyone help me dissect this error log? The class throwing this is almost identical to another class that works fine in the same program. The only difference is that I have added a List and am passing parameters to the url for the json request

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category","cat"));
```

Line 74:      JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_channels, "GET", params);

```
            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

07-01 00:17:21.573: D/dalvikvm(1009): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2585 objects / 167744 bytes in 78ms
07-01 00:17:28.133: W/dalvikvm(1009): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-01 00:17:28.253: E/AndroidRuntime(1009): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
07-01 00:17:28.253: E/AndroidRuntime(1009): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-01 00:17:28.253: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
07-01 00:17:28.253: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-01 00:17:28.253: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-01 00:17:28.253: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-01 00:17:28.253: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-01 00:17:28.253: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
07-01 00:17:28.253: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
07-01 00:17:28.253: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
07-01 00:17:28.253: E/AndroidRuntime(1009): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 00:17:28.253: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.example.video.unlimited.ListChannels$LoadAllChannels.doInBackground(ListChannels.java:74)
07-01 00:17:28.253: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.example.video.unlimited.ListChannels$LoadAllChannels.doInBackground(ListChannels.java:1)
07-01 00:17:28.253: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-01 00:17:28.253: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-01 00:17:28.253: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     ... 4 more
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009): Activity com.example.video.unlimited.ListChannels has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44ef2968 that was originally added here
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.video.unlimited.ListChannels has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44ef2968 that was originally added here
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at com.example.video.unlimited.ListChannels$LoadAllChannels.onPreExecute(ListChannels.java:63)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at com.example.video.unlimited.ListChannels.onCreate(ListChannels.java:45)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-01 00:17:29.762: E/WindowManager(1009):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you show us the function from ListChannels.java that contains line 74?

Comment: Edited and added line 74 Line 74 is JSONObject json = jParser.make...

Comment: Are you failing to initiate url_get_channels or jParser?

Comment: Nope, is done the same way in the other file.

Comment: my bad on the not giving up's...was something no initialized..jParser...:/ damnit

Answer (score 1):

What about the "android.view.WindowLeaked" exception?
This means that you are trying to show a Dialog from a "closed" activity.

Hope this helps
/Yaron